# Android Snackbar TextAlignment in Center

Tags: android

[image]

How to change the Snackbar text alignment to center ? bellow code is not working

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), intent.getStringExtra(KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snack.getView();
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(LoginActivity.this, R.color.red_EC1C24));
tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
snack.show();
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

**EDIT**

The appearance of `Snackbar` was changed in `Support` library v23 so the correct answer now is:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
} else {
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}
```

Comment: I can't get the desired effect with just the setGravity (i.e. without setTextAlignment, which is for API 17). I am using the support libs 23.2.0...

Comment: @kevinze I made it just with setTextAlignment and without setGravity, with support 23.3.0 on API 23.

Answer (score 36):

Try this:

```
// make snackbar
Snackbar mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.intro_snackbar, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
// get snackbar view
View mView = mSnackbar.getView();
// get textview inside snackbar view
TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
// set text to center
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    mTextView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
else
    mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
// show the snackbar
mSnackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 8):

The above conditional `setTextAlignment() OR setGravity()` solution didn't work for me.

For **bulletproof** centered text:

1. Always apply `setGravity()`
2. Apply `setTextAlignment()` for API >= 17

And note the support library change in **AndroidX**. If using AndroidX, lookup the TextView by `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text` instead of `android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text`.

Code:

```
TextView sbTextView = (TextView) findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);

sbTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    sbTextView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The code below does the trick for me:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
if(tv!=null) {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
       tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

   tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, using XML:

- Your main theme has to inherit from `Theme.MaterialComponents`, and has to delcare its own styling for `Snackbar` and its `TextView` as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/MySnackbar</item>
    <item name="snackbarTextViewStyle">@style/MySnackbarTextView</item>
</style>
```

- `Theme.MaterialComponents` adds a margin to the snackbar, and it changes its animation. If you want the `AppCompat` style, do as follows:

```
<style name="MySnackbar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
    ...
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
    <item name="animationMode">slide</item>
</style>
```

- Finally, we can edit our `TextView`:

```
<style name="MySnackbarTextView" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView">
    ...
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

androidX solution for H/V center:

```
public class SnackBarCentered{
    private Snackbar snackbar;

    public void show(String message){
        if (snackbar != null)
            snackbar.dismiss();//Dismiss the previous snackbar if any
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(this.binding.getRoot(), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        View view = snackbar.getView();
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        params.width=FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
        //Replace with android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text if you are not using androidX
        if(tv!=null) {
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);
        }
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use "com.google.android.material" instead of "android.support.design.R" as it is no more supported after androidx migration.

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.copyright, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            View mView = mSnackbar.getView();
            TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
                mTextView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            else
                mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            mSnackbar.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following code it's work for set snackbar text in center:

```
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(main_layout, "This is snack", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
    Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    mTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    snackbar.show();
```