# How to align message textview to the center in snackbar?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-snackbar

How to align message textview to the center Horizontally in snackbar in android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center text horizontally and vertically in a TextView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-textview-in-android) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668217/android-snackbar-textalignment-in-center

Comment: This is not duplicate. This question regards Snackbar or CoordinatorLayout in android. Sorry it is not duplicate question. Thanks

Comment: Snackbar text-message is of AppCompatTextview type which can be aligned desirously as it happened with normal textview.     

AppCompatTextView tv = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Below is a sample, for making the Snackbar Text center horizontal

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), "Hello", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
snackbar.show();
View view = snackbar.getView();
TextView txtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
txtv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

If you are using androidX

then replace the `textview` id `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`

Comment: For AndroidX, the correct view id for the TextView is ```com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set both **textAlignment** and **Gravity** to the **Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL**

```
snackTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);   
snackTextView.setTextAlignment(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```