# Android design library Snackbar - getting TextView returns Null

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-snackbar

I'm trying to get hold of the `Snackbar`'s `TextView`. This is the code I'm using:

```
 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mRecyclerView, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
 View view = snackbar.getView();
 TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
```

Running the above always sets `tv` to null. I'm using design library version `23.0.0` and in the layout resource for the snackbar, I can see the `TextView` with id `snackbar_text`. What am I missing?

Comment: Its working properly. Try it once again. Check `Snackbar.make(mRecyclerView, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);` You have to pass parent object of your xml. You should check `mRecyclerView` in your code.

Comment: Which parent object? Fragment layout? Activity layout?

Comment: Yes if you use in Fragment then get main parent(First layout) object of your `my_frgment.xml` and if you use in Activity then get main parent(First layout) object of your `my_activity.xml`

Comment: I've changed the mRecyclerView to the fragment's root view - still the same problem

Comment: Try it with Activity's root view.

Comment: Yeah, still a null.. Must be something else..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108511/discussion-between-harsh-patel-and-vkislicins).

Comment: According to the documentation, `Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given to view.` - so it shouldn't be necessary to provide an absolute parent

Comment: Why do you need to get the view inside the snackbar?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Wanted to center the text horizontally when there are no action buttons

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694059/how-to-align-message-textview-to-the-center-in-snackbar

Comment: TextView is still null regardless of whether I call show before or after.

Answer (score 12):

**For those who came are having trouble finding an up-to-date answer on this, I'm here to help.**

Many examples show the use of this res id:

`android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text`

It has since been replaced with:

`com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`

**Example:**

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make( /*however you decide to make it*/ );
View view = snackbar.getView();
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
//make your needed changes...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by not using the id from *android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text*.

If you look at the source of the design support library you can see that `R.id.snackbar_text` is set to:

```
public static final int snackbar_text = 0x7f0c006b;
```

If you look at the value of `android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text` in your App, you can see that the value is:

```
public static final int snackbar_text = 0x7f0b006b;
```

For me, this issue only happens if I use the Design Support Library in a library module.

Comment: Right... this issue only happens if I use the Design Support Library in a library module, but your solution doesn't work for me. I tried replacing android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text with R.id.snackbar_text and code compiles fine but textview still retruns null. Read my answer below to know how i solved the issue..

Comment: I wrote a small lib to be able to style snackbars and it looks like using R.id.snackbar_text works using support design lib 23.4.0. The code is available at https://github.com/UlrichRaab/snackbar-builder/blob/master/snackbar-builder/src/main/java/de/ulrichraab/snackbar/SnackbarStyle.java

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! You VERY help me :).

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work:

```
View containerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foo, container, false); 
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(containerView, "snackbar text", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT); 
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView(); 
TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
text.setText("It works"); snackbar.show();
```

Comment: Not sure you're reading that answer correctly. They are also getting `TextView` before calling .show() method

Comment: this is the code that works for me (in a `Fragment`):
`View containerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foo, container, false);
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(containerView, "snackbar text", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        text.setText("It works");
        snackbar.show();`

Comment: No, this is not correct. You definitely, 100% don't want to inflate your fragment from within a fragment. And you should be able to provide any view to Snackbar, and Snackbar will search for the root parent on its own.

Comment: Why wouldn't you inflate your fragment within the fragment itself?? See [this link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

Answer (score 0):

This issues came only after I added library module with Design support  dependency and I removed the design support dependency from my main module.
I added the design support gradle dependency again in my main module and it works!

That means following dependency is added in both the main module "app" and a helper library module which is added as library in my "app":

```
compile "com.android.support:design:$project.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
```

where project.ext.supportLibraryVersion is defined in my app.build.gradle like below:

```
allprojects {
    project.ext {
    supportLibraryVersion="23.3.0"
    }
}
```

But I'm still not sure why it works after adding design support dependency in both modules while it should have worked if i add the dependency only in library module which i am anyway adding as library for my "app" module? Can anyone help me understand this? Thanks in advance!